# Image with embedded links?

Tags: image, hyperlink, embed, html

I need to embed links within an image, on a google webpage, that will send you to other webpages. More specifically, it is an interactive image of a cell, that should allow you to click on individual organelles (subcellular regions), and be given information about each via a link to a different site. I figured it would need to be coded, and that coordinates of each of these locations on the image would be required as well... but I am programming-challenged and if there exists a more simple method or webpage that does this for you, that would be fantastic. Thank you so much for helping! Any information is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need the `<map>` tag!

This example from [W3School](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp) shows how it works:

> The  tag is used to define a client-side image-map. An image-map
>   is an image with clickable areas.
>
> The required name attribute of the `<map>` element is associated with
>   the `<img>`'s usemap attribute and creates a relationship between the
>   image and the map.
>
> The  element contains a number of `<area>` elements, that **defines
>   the clickable areas** in the image map.

```
<img src="planets.gif" width="145" height="126" alt="Planets" usemap="#planetmap">

<map name="planetmap">
  <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,82,126" href="sun.htm" alt="Sun">
  <area shape="circle" coords="90,58,3" href="mercur.htm" alt="Mercury">
  <area shape="circle" coords="124,58,8" href="venus.htm" alt="Venus">
</map>
```

There are online tools [like this one](http://www.maschek.hu/imagemap/imgmap) that let you build that html code right from your browser.